# parse JSON data using jq and convert into csv

Tags: shell-script, jq

I am downloading api json data and converting into my final result as a csv file.

The sample data is in the below form:

```
{
    "content": [{
            "Title": "abc",
            "brand": "xyz",
            "information": {
                "c1": "101",
                "c2": "11111",
                "c3": "a,b,c,d,e:abc."
            }
        },
        {
            "Title": "RX100",
            "brand": "Yamaha",
            "information": {
                "c1": "102",
                "c2": "22222",
                "c3": "a."
            }
        },
        {
            "Title": "victor",
            "brand": "TVS",
            "information": {
                "c1": "103",
                "c2": "33333",
                "c3": "a,b,c"
            }
        },
        {
            "Title": "R15",
            "brand": "Yamaha",
            "information": {
                "c1": "104",
                "c2": "44444",
                "c3": "a,b"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have successfully downloaded and converted into multiple csv on the basis of number of Title.
Data looks like in the below form after converting in multiple csv file.

```
Headers-> c1,c2,c3
csv1-->   101,11111,a,b,c,d,e:abc.
csv2-->   102,22222,a.
csv3-->   103,33333,a,b,c.
csv4-->   104,44444,a,b.
```

but I want the above data in below form.

```
Headers-> c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7
csv1-->   101,11111,a,b,c,d,e:abc.
csv2-->   102,22222,a.
csv3-->   103,33333,a,b,c.
csv4-->   104,44444,a,b.
```

Is it possible to divide the c3 into different number of columns on the basis of "," present in my json file using json. The column c3 will get divided on the basis of number of elements are present and  will be the maximum value of c3 data.

Answer (score 7):

For this exact data,

```
jq -r '.content[].information | [.c1, .c2, .c3] | join(",")' < sample.json
```

will work - just inserting commas between the three columns replicates the effect of a joined-upCSV file. For more complex real data, particularly with numbers, this will work better:

```
jq -r '.content[].information | [.c1, .c2, (.c3|split(",")|.[])] | @csv' < sample.json
```

This one is all fairly standard up to `.c3|split(",")|.[]`, which

1. Extracts column 3's value
2. Splits that value into an array on commas
3. Flattens that array out

`@csv` then converts the array into CSV format. This produces the following output for your sample file:

```
"101","11111","a","b","c","d","e:abc."
"102","22222","a."
"103","33333","a","b","c"
"104","44444","a","b"
```

If you don't want quotes, the most reliable thing is to use `@tsv` and just replace the tabs:

```
jq -r '.content[].information|[.c1, .c2, .c3|split(",")|.[]] | @tsv|gsub("\t"; ",")' < sample.json
```

If all your values are strings you could also use `join(",")` again.

---

If you want the literal header line `c1,...c7` created as well, this will do it:

```
jq -r '[.content[].information|[.c1, .c2, (.c3|split(",")|.[])]] | (([range([.[] | length] | max)|"c" + (.+1|tostring)]|join(",")), (.[] | join(",")))' < sample.json
```

There's three parts: the first creates the arrays of columns as before, and then the other two parts use that as input:

1. `([range([.[] | length] | max)|"c" + (.+1|tostring)]|join(","))` generates the header line: it finds the maximum length of any row by generating an array of row lengths, creates a range 0..maximum and maps over it to create an array of "c1".."c7", then joins them all together with commas.
2. `(.[] | join(","))` is analogous to our second half from earlier, and the same things about `@csv` apply.

Comment: Thanks @Homer . I will try it and will update about the result. just out of curiosity is it possible to get the data in below format also or it can be done only after converting csv?                                                                                                                             csv1-->   101,11111,a
    101,11111,b
    101,11111,c
    101,11111,d
    101,11111,e:abc

csv2-->   102,22222,a
csv3-->   103,33333,a
    103,33333,b
    103,33333,c
csv4-->   104,44444,a
    104,44444,b

Comment: To remove unnecessary quotes from `@csv`, one could pass the output through `csvformat` from the `csvkit` toolbox.  That way, quotes that _are_ needed will be kept.

Comment: @Homer, I am getting below error during  this "jq -r '[.content[].information|[.c1, .c2, .c3|split(",")|.[]]] | (([range([.[] | length] | max)|"c" + (.+1|tostring)]|join(",")), (.[] | join(",")))' < sample.json" .                                                                                             Error : "split input and separator must be strings"

Comment: It sounds like your real data doesn't match the sample data and some of the values are not strings. I've put an extra pair of parentheses in to handle the case where something other than c3 is a non-string, but if the data is heterogeneous to the point that any c3 is not a string you may need a different tack to massage the data first.